# Почему индекс выходит за границы массива?

Tags: c#

```
var tasks = new Task[queenCount];
for (int i = 0; i < queenCount; i++)
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => CalculatePeacefulArrangement(queenCount, chessTables[i], queenCount, resultArray, i));
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

И например, прописав от руки все вызываемые методы через `Parallel.Invoke` все работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < queenCount; i++) 
{
  int index = i; 
  tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => CalculatePeacefulArrangement(queenCount, chessTables[index], queenCount, resultArray, index));
}
```

Переменная `i`, которая в цикле захватывается анонимными лямбда-функциями (в Вашем коде), - одна на всех. К моменту исполнения этих анонимных функций значение `i` с большой вероятностью изменилось. Даже если Вы не получили выход за границу массива, значение этой переменной в момент вызова `CalculatePeacefulArrangement` - не то, что Вы ожидаете.

С переменной `index`, объявленной внутри блока, каждая анонимная функция видит свой экземпляр `index`, имеющий значение, которое присвоено переменной `index` на соответствующей итерации цикла.

Comment: Это и правда работает, но не могли бы вы объяснить почему?